# Fix immediate cyclic references with discriminated unions

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, circular-reference, discriminated-union

I'm making a mini Pascal parser, [this Pascal syntax](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/vihavain/k06/okk/items/minipascalsyntax.html) supports declaring infinite types:

> program ::= **program** identifier **;** block **.**
>
> block ::= variable-declaration-part procedure-declaration-part statement-part
>
> procedure-declaration-part ::= { procedure-declaration **;** }
>
> procedure-declaration ::= **procedure** identifier **;** block

I try to create AST domain types for this syntax:

```
type Program = Identifier * Block
and Block = VariableDeclaration list option * ProcedureDeclaration list option * Statement list
and ProcedureDeclaration = Identifier * Block
```

But the compiler would throw an error, because I use type aliases, and they are erased at compile-time:

> This type definition involves an immediate cyclic reference through an abbreviation

Some said I could fix this problem with wrapped discriminated union types, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
and ProcedureDeclaration = ProcedureDeclaration of Identifier * Block
```

Now rather than just a tuple, it's a single-case DU type, which you can create with e.g.

```
ProcedureDeclaration(someID, someBlock)
```

and decompose with

```
match somePD with
| ProcedureDeclaration(i,b) -> ...
```